# Java: Best way to delegate to method w/o waiting for it to complete

Tags: java

I have a AWS SQS listener that, when it receives a message, invokes the proper method to handle it. The problem is that it also waits for that method to return, and if it takes longer than the visibility timeout, we get the message again. Take this for instance:

```
if (FULL_LOAD.equalsIgnoreCase(msg.getLoadType())) {
    //Create the controller and process the message
    log.info("Process valid Full Load message from "+msg.getDataSourceName());
    productRefService.fullRefresh(ctx);
    jobCompletion(msg, jobStart, start);
}
// continue processing
```

So right now, before the listener can continue, it must wait for `productRefService.fullRefresh` to complete, which can be up to 15 minutes. It seems to me there should be a way to invoke the service method and continue, but I'm not sure how that would look. Make `productRefService` async?? Use the `Callable` interface? I'm not interested in the return value - I just want the listener freed up.

Comment: Good question!  If you're on Java 8 or higher, consider [CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming): [Guide To CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! But don't all of the `Future` methods require a return value?

Comment: Yes, but if you read the link: "If we don't need to return a value down the Future chain, we can use an instance of the Consumer functional interface. Its single method takes a parameter and returns void."  Java "CompletableFutures" are analogous to Javascript ["Promises"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or C# ["async/await"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).  The asynchronous "Task" gives the caller something to "wait on" (if it needs to).

Comment: Got it. You should make your comment the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request:

> Good question! If you're on Java 8 or higher, consider
> [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):
>
> - [Asynchronous Programming in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming)
> - [Guide To
>   CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)
>
> A Java "CompletableFuture" is analogous to Javascript ["Promises"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or C#
> ["async/await"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). It's return value gives the caller something to "wait
> on" (if it needs to).